# How to reduce size of checkbox in windows phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

Hi iam new to windows phone 7.

Iam using checkbox controls in my app.

But the size of checkbox control is not reducing.

I changed height, width, background properties all, but no result.

In my screen iam going to use 30 check boxes without scroll panels.

Thats why iam going to reduce their size.
plz help me

Comment: You might want to rethink your design - the check boxes are that size to be usable in a touch environment; if you were successful in resizing them, it might not be usable.

Comment: ofcourse, you are right. but we need to achieve it as a developer, how can we do it.

Comment: You'll make it easier to help you if you show what you've tried already. You should also note that the default checkbox styling includes padding that makes it easier to be sure you're taping the one you want. If you start putting them close together it'll be easier for users to accidentally tap the wrong one.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. I just want the checkbox without the layout for its associated label.

Answer (score 3):

Although I agree with the comments above, sometimes UI design can be compromised -

You can achieve it by adding a ScaleX and ScaleY :

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeSmall}" 
                      BorderThickness="1">
    <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
    </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
</CheckBox>
```

This worked for me in WP8 - haven't tested in WP7